# Why only one row is showing in report?

Tags: jasper-reports

In MySQL workbench I get 3 rows:

```
mysql> select * from person;
+-----+------+
| ID  | NAME |
+-----+------+
| A01 | A01  |
| A02 | A02  |
| A03 | A03  |
+-----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when I use jrxml and show to pdf

I just can get a one row

```
+-----+------+
| ID  | NAME |
+-----+------+
| A01 | A01  |
+-----+------+
```

and this's my jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="T0113" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" >
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from person ]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="ID">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="NAME">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="240" y="0" width="100" height="30" />
                <text><![CDATA[PDFPDF]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="170" y="15" width="100" height="30" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="10" width="100" height="30" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

So how to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you field's are in the **wrong** band.

> **Column Header** This section appears at the beginning of each column in
>   the generated document.
>
> **Detail**    This section is repeated for each line of data supplied by the
>   report's data source. The detail section can be made of multiple
>   bands.

Currently you have them in the `columnHeader` you need to but them in the `detail` band

```
<detail>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="170" y="15" width="100" height="30" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="320" y="10" width="100" height="30" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

To learn more about different report sections see [Tutorial report section](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_sections.htm) and [JRBand API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRBand.html)

Answer (score 0):

just change `<![CDATA[$F{ID}]]>` and `<![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]>` in the detail band NOT in columnHeader